# Xcode Error - No such file or directory

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to build a project of mine that includes [fuzzylite](http://code.google.com/p/fuzzy-lite/) C++ libraries within a Carbon C++ application. However the compiler throws out an error for each fuzzylite's library I include in my source code. I've tried to include the **Header Search Path** and the **Library Search Path** on my target application build info but it doesn't work.
I've included the header file using double quote markers just like the following example:

> #include "fuzzylite/test.h"

How can I include such library in my project and get it to work properly?

Comment: You did use `#include "fuzzylite/test.h"`, right? Not just the name of the file?

Comment: Yeah Luchian. I properly typed the keyword #include before the library inclusion stated above ;)

Comment: If this library isn't installed as a framework, then a leading path like `fuzzylite/` will be interpreted literally as a directory relative to your search path.  For example, if you were to set the search path to `/usr/local/include`, there would have to be a `/usr/local/include/fuzzylite/test.h` file.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I guess I haven't get how the .h and .cpp files are bounded by Xcode yet. I've tried to do it in an other way now: I've compiled fuzzylite library using makefile, process which gave me a '.a' static library file. I wonder how could I use this file in my project. I guess it's much more easy to use static libraries rather then headers and implementation files. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you need clean the path: #include "fuzzylite/test.h" for ALL #include, like this: #include "test.h"

Answer (score 0):

From version 3.1, you should use `#include fl/Headers.h`.

If you are running into problems, I strongly encourage you to report the problem in the forums at http://www.fuzzylite.com, where I and others will be very happy to help you.